# Hive - Use of replace or regexp_replace function for multiple replace conditions

Tags: sql, regex, replace, hive, regexp-replace

I am using Hive and trying to clean up data that may have multiple unwanted data. Would like to know if I can use a single regexp_replace  or translate function for multiple conditions.

For Eg. If the string is `2000 Helen St - DO NOT USE` 
I need to replace/trim `- DO NOT USE` and also change `St` to `Street`. 
The output should be `2000 Helen Street`.

Similarly

- `3000 Cross St` should be `3000 Cross Street`,
- `4000 Mascot Dr` should be `4000 Mascot Drive`
- etc..

There are about 10 or more such clean up conditions, and the input string could either meet 0 or multiple conditions criteria. Can these conditions be set up in a single `regexp_replace`?

Comment: can you show some examples of clean up conditions? also include your attempt so far.

Comment: For me, it seems that you are going to have a set of transformation rule and using `regexp_replace` multiple times should not be a `clean` solution. Rather think about writing a simple  `GenericUDF`, which would take care of all scenario. And it comes with power of Java, so there are endless possibility of cleaning all type of data.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily combine templates for removing substrings or replacing with the same value using OR (|). In other cases, use multiple regexp_replace:

For example, if you want to remove 'TEST' and '- DO NOT USE' and replace 'Dr' with 'Street':

```
hive> select regexp_replace(
                  regexp_replace('TEST 2000 Helen St - DO NOT USE',
                                 '[- ]*DO NOT USE|TEST( *|$)',''),
                          'St([ ]*|$)','Street'  
                  );
OK
2000 Helen Street
Time taken: 0.055 seconds, Fetched: 1 row(s)
```

It removes 'TEST' and  '- DO NOT USE' - these combined into single template. 'St' replaced with 'Street' - this is second regexp_replace.
Of course this is example only.

Comment: i think you can simply use a nested `replace` instead of `regexp_replace`.

Comment: @VamsiPrabhala Maybe, it's depends on complexity of patterns

Comment: it also depends on what version of Hive you're running— older versions will not have `replace`.